# import Excel File Data into Alfresco Datalist

Tags: import, alfresco, alfresco-share, datalist, alfresco-webscripts

I have more than one-thousands records in excel sheet. now i want to import those records into data list in alfresco. But it seems to be very bad practice to copy those records one by one to data-list. so is there any way to import all records from excel to data-list in alfresco. my alfresco version is community 5.2 , i made custom data-list with the same columns in alfresco but i don't know how to import these data from excel to it. i found some solution for export Data-list to excel , but for import i could not find any things.
could any on help me ?  is there any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

For converting excel data to Data List, There's no OOTB feature. you'll have to create your custom logic. The easiest way would be to write a java based webscript that takes your excel and using a library for parsing (e.g. [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)) iterates through each row in the excel and add values to your datalist.

To add data list from code refer [documentation](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-data-lists.html). it contains both java and js example. Add your custom datalist URI and properties.

PS: There is an [extension](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-7496-alfresco-share-datalist-extension). but its for community 5.0.

Comment: thank you for reply , i wrote a java class to read and parse Excel file and use a  Apache POI , it's Ok and work Correctly , but i don't know how use it for alfresco data-list ...... , about the Extension that you suggest : this is just for exporting data-list to excel and add filter for data-list search but dont have a import option